# How to set up Mongoose schema to store an array of objects in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I currently have an `array` that contains multiple `objects` nested inside of it.

***Here is the format...***

```
[ { id: 1, title: 'Squats', video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPYCiuiB4PA' }, { id: 2, title: 'Push-Ups',video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPYCiuiB4PA' }]
```

***I am attempting to `.save()` it in my `Schedule` model that looks like this...***

```
var ScheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    schedule: [Object]
})
```

When I run the following code in the `Schedule` controller on the server side, the `.save()` function gives me a 'success' message (that I programmed it to give), but when I look inside my `MongoDB` database, it saves incorrectly with nothing inside of the `schedule` array.

***This is what the saved information looks like in the database....***

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c28a0d4c92bec03408c077"), "schedule" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
```

I have  a feeling my model is set up wrong.

***Model  schemas I have tried...***

1) `schedule: []`
2) `schedule: [Schema.Types.Mixed]`

***Just in case this is helpful, here is my `.save()` function when I try to save said data from the schedule controller...***

```
var new_schedule = new Schedule(req.body.info);
new_schedule.save(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('err');
    }else{
        console.log('worked');
    }
})
```

Comment: Really unclear as to your intent. *"I have an array that contains multiple objects in it.."*. Okay, where? Is it in a text file as a string in JSON format? Have you created this object in memory? Is this the result of some other function? Then of course what do you intend to do for storage? Are these meant to be separate documents? Are these instead members of an array contained in a single document? Are you even then aware that a "Schema" refers to the standard structure of fields defined in a document. So many questions raised here, and you appear to have but taken a glance at documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest setting up your schema like this:

```
var ScheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    schedule: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]
});
```

That would be the proper way to set it up. Another way to do it would be to define the object in-line, like this:

```
var ScheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    schedule: [{
        id: { type: Number, default: 1 },
        title: { type: String, default: '', trim: true },
        video: { type: String, default: '', trim: true }
    }]
});
```

Also, it may not be a problem on the server side code. Before you create the new Schedule with req.body.info, you might want to put in a line like this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2));
```

This will print out the req.body object in a readable format so that you can make sure the client app is sending the information you think you are getting.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your response. After spending time looking at the Mongoose documentation, your first solution is what I went for. That isn't working through unfortunately. Your other solution isn't working either, because not all objects in the array have the same attributes. This is why I went for the `Mixed` schema in the first place. It is mind boggling...

Comment: AH HAH! Ok, so basically all of the models I have used thus far are completely valid. Everything you furnished was also valid. The problem I ran into was actually in my server side controller....
`var new_schedule = new Schedule(req.body.info);`
Notice anything fishy? 
I didn't include the `schedule` key while creating a new Schedule. I t should look something like this...
`var new_schedule = new Schedule({schedule: req.body.info});`
You get the point for furnishing the right answers to my model question though. Thanks!

Comment: Ah well there we go. Glad my answer helped. That's why I suggested doing the console.log - it shows you exactly what you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a model of inline objects in schema.
2. Use this :

   ```
   var model = mongoose.model("CollectionName",SchemaName);
   model.insertMany(arrayOfSchedules , function(err,docs){});
   ```